# Timer and localstorage issue

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am quite new to Javascript and web programming and currently learning localStorage and I have found some code and I tried to modify it. What I am trying to do, when the set time is up, I want to call another function named **whatever function.**. Please help.

Note: If there is any problem in terms of rule of Stack overflow, Let me know. I will edit & delete the question.

JS

```
var finishTime;
var timerLength = 10;
var timeoutID;
dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + timerLength;


if(localStorage.getItem('myTime')){
    Update();

}


$('#save').click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('myTime', ((new Date()).getTime() + timerLength * 1000));
    if (timeoutID != undefined) window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    Update();

});

function Update() {
    finishTime = localStorage.getItem('myTime');
    var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date().getTime());
    dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + Math.max(timeLeft/1000,0);

    if(timeLeft <= 0){
      console.log('please work');
    }else{
       timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 100);
    }
}
```

view

```
<p id="display">Time Left
    <p>
        <button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: The code reference: http://jsfiddle.net/5f5qexre/387/

Comment: In your Update() function, just check if timeLeft <= 0. If so, call your other function. Also, when it is <=0 you probably want to clear your timeoutID in that case too.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Hi Chris, thanks for your answer I edited my code basically I added like `if (timeLeft <=0) {whateversomethingfunction(); }` called. but the problem is when I open the window, the initial value is '0' like before I 'save' the form. is that possible to make it like when timer started and when it reaches to number '0' then call the function. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't try your code but this line:

`var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date());`

shouldn't be?

`var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date().getTime());`

added the `.getTime()`

edit:

`function Update() {
    finishTime = localStorage.getItem('myTime');
    var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date().getTime());
    dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + Math.max(timeLeft/1000,0);`

if (timeLeft <= 0){
      localStorage.removeItem('myTime'); //<=remove
      whateversomethingfunctuin();
      // console.log('Seems');
   } else {
     //call only when needed 
     timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 100);
   }
}

Comment: oh yeah both are working fine. Thanks for that, hmm can you please help me to figure out the question, if you dont mind so basically when times up, it stays '0' which means keep call the function like i have set but what I am currently trying to do is when `timeLeft` is '0' call the function and get out of the `if condition`. I tried to put `console.log` which prints out `seems` but it keeps printing out since timeLeft is 0 when times up..

Comment: check the edit, you should call setTimeout only when needed.... 100 is too fast... does it work now?

Comment: if you used clearTimeout should work too... not sure what you are doing inside that whatever function...

Comment: Man, I really want to say "it is working!" but unfortunately that doesnt start counting.. when I click the `#save` button

Comment: then timeleft is always <= 0, did you change the .getTime()? update your post with the actual code

Comment: in your html there is `id="start"` is "start" or "save"?

Comment: oh man, don't worry about the id. sorry about the confusion. I updated my code and the codes is actually counting when 'save' is hit but when the times up and when i reload the page it prints out `whateversomethingfunction()` again since the value is '0'....

Comment: I am trying to trigger the `whateversomethingfunction()` only when the `save`button clicked and when the timer reachs to timerlength(10seconds) then trigger the `whateversomethingfunction()`...

Comment: AH I TOTALLY FORGOT to use removeItem and really appreciate that